# Sublime/TAG - "Remove Picked Attributes From Tags" won't work with "data-reactid"

Tags: html, tags, attributes, sublimetext3

i'm trying to use TAG in Sublime Text 3 -- https://github.com/titoBouzout/Tag

When i use "Remove Picked Attributes From Tags (in Document)" with

> class

it removes all class attributes successfully.

But when i use it with

> data-reactid

it do nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Jens

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate. I have the following HTML: `<div data-reactid="foobar"> Some stuff.</div>`. Selecting your option from the **`Edit -> Tag`** menu, the HTML becomes `<div> Some stuff.</div>`. I'm using Build 3111 on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo for rechecking this issue. Strangly - after one night of sleep and a new start - it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Switch off your computer - go to bed - and try this the next day again. Then it will work.